# Need help rewriting a url with JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, userscripts

I have a userscript (http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/179402) that I'm writing that adds a bar to Google Sites like the one they removed. I'm needing the script to take the value of the search field and add it to a url (Replacement URL) and have it replace the url (Original URL) on the bar. In other words, I need to update it where the search term carries over to other pages, like the original google bar they removed.

I've tried this a few different ways. One way I tried was getting the value this way. Which, gets the value fine.

```
$('#gbqfq').keyup(function() {
var searchterm = this.value;
});
```

Then I've tried  to add the search term to a url that replaces the original URL this way

```
var url1search = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+searchterm;
$('#url1').attr("href", url1search);
```

How do you replace a url with a new url plus a variable?

I'm very new to JavaScript, I'm making this script to try to learn it. If someone can help me figure out how to do this I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah sorry, I see your problem. `searchterm` is only defined inside the anonymous function, it would be undefined elsewhere. Try moving rest of the script inside that function too.

Comment: Ah, that worked! That makes a lot of sense now, I understand why it wasn't working. Thank you.

Comment: No problemo and sorry about the snappy first response. Too tired to think straight. :(

Comment: No need to be sorry, I didn't bluntly ask it. You helped me out, I appreciate it. This has been bugging me for a while. lol